# Line wrapping list responsive to screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I suspect this to be a javascript trick but please feel free to tell me that there is a pure-CSS way to do this.

I have a list of items (in this case pictures) that I want to show in a grid like layout.
My requirements are simple:

- Equal spacing between each item
- "Justified" alignment, i.e. 1st element of a row stick to left, last element stick to right.
- ***The number of items per row changes based on screen width.***

I have tried a few things but each with some problems:

- `li.item { padding-right: somepx; } li.item:nth-child { padding-right: 0px; }`

  - nth-child needs to change as screen size changes.
- `li.item { padding-left: some/2px; padding-right: some/2px; }`

  - 1st and last item will not stick to the edge.

As you can see, I was able to achieve only 2 out of 3 requirements above, any good cross-browser compatible trick that can enlighten me?

Thanks!